# Largest Even Number in an Array using Swift

Tags: swift, max

I'm a beginner in Swift, I'm trying to make a function that determines the largest even number in an array, here's my code that's not working:

```
func largestEven(array: [Int]) -> Int {

let array = [5,12,6,8]
    
var evenArray = array.filter({$0 % 2 == 0})
    
let highestEven = evenArray.max()

return highestEven

}

print(largestEven(array: [5,12,6,8]))
```

Comment: "Not working" means what in technical terms?

Comment: While the error was clear in this case, for future questions please make sure to include the error message in your question (or a description of the incorrect behavior, if there isn't an error message) so people don't have to try to guess what's wrong.

Comment: Just for fun single iteration solution `array.reduce(nil) { $1.isMultiple(of: 2) && $1 > ($0 ?? .min) ? $1 : $0 }`

Comment: Lmao, here's a preposterous solution `array.max { $1.isMultiple(of: 2) && (!$0.isMultiple(of: 2) || $0 < $1) }`, just for fun. I made it by starting with a closure that uses a switch statement to branch on the even/oddness of any two elements under comparison, like `switch ($0.isMultiple(of: 2), $1.isMultiple(of: 2))`. It returns `true` if `$1` is even but `$0` is odd, and returns `$0 < $1` if both are even, and false in every other case. From there you can simplify it down to this single boolean expression

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica this would return `5` for `[5]`

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica resuming this will always return the first element of a collection with only odd numbers and it would only return `nil` for empty collections.

Comment: @LeoDabus Ahhhh, good find! So it seems that a single-`max` call isn't sufficient to solve this problem, because you have no way of "injecting" `nil` to receive as the output of the process applies to an only-odd input. Oh well :) It was nightmare code golf code, I just wrong it here for fun, I thought it was a little clever :p

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
func largestEven(array: [Int]) -> Int {
```

to

```
func largestEven(array: [Int]) -> Int? {
```

The reason is that `max()` yields an Optional Int, because the array might be empty. So you cannot return a simple Int; you must return that Optional.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you define a local array in your function.

A simple implementation could be something like (note the optional Int as return type):

```
func largestEven(array: [Int]) -> Int? {
    array.filter { $0.isMultiple(of: 2) }.max()
}
```

Comment: You could `.lazy` it to prevent the intermediate array allocation.